# How to refer to a built-in op when writing a custom user op

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm writing a custom op in tensorflow, and I would like to refer to an op that already exists, either one of my own user ops, or one of the built-in ops. Is there any way to do this without just copy pasting the code from the other op that I'm referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is "it depends." Only some of the built-in ops are factored in a reusable way. For example, the component-wise ops are implemented as [reusable functors](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/04de87f1204103cf9b753858ecae33099aafb4c2/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L573), so you may be able to `#include "tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h"` and use the `UnaryFunctor` or `BinaryFunctor` classes if your needs to borrow some of their functionality.

Most other ops have their implementations inlined into the `Compute()` method of the corresponding `OpKernel`. For your own custom ops, you are free to define the implementation in free functions, or to use inheritance to define common functionality that is shared between ops.